# redirect folder urls into onepager

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect all files from the folder **web** into the new onepager website. There is a deleted wordpress installation with google links.

The urls in the folder web looks like

```
http://example.com/web/a/b/c
http://example.com/web/ab/cd
```

What I need is a redirect into a new Domain like

```
http://new-domain.com/
```

Here is my Code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```